# Distinct command in django

Tags: python, django, orm

[image]

what will be the ORM queries for the following situation:

```
Count of child accounts(account_child_id)

Count the number of accounts won(stage=Won).

Count the number of distinct accounts with potential=’HP’

Count the number of distinct accounts with pipeline=’HP’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [Django - Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/)

1. `Account.objects.filter(account_child_id__isnull=False).count()`
2. `Account.objects.filter(stage='Won').count()`
3. `Account.objects.filter(potential='HP').distinct('account_id').count()`
4. `Account.objects.filter(pipeline='HP').distinct('account_id').count()`

Comment: 3rd and 4th query printing duplicate rows, see 3rd query should return 2 objects only instead of 6 objects